# Add field of array element in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents containing an array of objects:

```js
db.collection.insert({
    arr: [
      { id: 1, text: 'foo' },
      { id: 2, text: 'bar' },
    ]
});
```

Is there a way to extract/project/add a field of **one** element in that array? For example, the `text` field of the first element of the array. I've tried various variations of [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) in [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LEBQ1QjppEl),

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
      $addFields: { text1: '$arr.text' }
  }
]);
```

but nothing produced just one `text` field. At best, I got both, with the syntax above, but I want only one field, in order to use $type on it, because it appears [`$type` can't inspect array elements](https://github.com/mongodb/docs/pull/3586).

Answer (score 7):

You can use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) with [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to define temporary variable and then reference it to get `text` field:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            text1: {
                $let: {
                    vars: {
                        first: {
                            $arrayElemAt: [ "$arr", 0 ]
                        }
                    },
                    in: "$$first.text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: How do you add all the items by a specific key on the item/object and not just the first?

Answer (score 3):

One way to extract a field of an array element is to project the first element using [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) in a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage, then to access the desired field, e.g. `text`, in a second `$project` stage:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      elem1: {
        $arrayElemAt: ["$arr", 0]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      text1: "$elem1.text"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DqVFLdNEByU).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative I've found is using [`first`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) and [`$getField`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/getField/) which is new since Version 5.0

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: { 
      text1: {
        $getField: {
          field: 'text',
          input: { $first: '$arr' }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```